# Issues using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to Use JSON.NET to parse response from an API.

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "channels": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxx",
            "name": "xx",
            "created": "xxxxx",
            "creator": "xxxxxx",
            "is_archived": false,
            "is_member": false,
            "num_members": 2,
            "is_general": false,
            "topic": {
                "value": "",
                "creator": "",
                "last_set": "0"
            },
            "purpose": {
                "value": "",
                "creator": "",
                "last_set": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxxx",
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "created": "xxxxxx",
            "creator": "xxxxxxx",
            "is_archived": false,
            "is_member": true,
            "num_members": 3,
            "is_general": true,
            "topic": {
                "value": "",
                "creator": "",
                "last_set": "0"
            },
            "purpose": {
                "value": "xxxxx",
                "creator": "",
                "last_set": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "name": "xxxxxxx",
            "created": "xxxxxx",
            "creator": "xxxxxx",
            "is_archived": false,
            "is_member": false,
            "num_members": 2,
            "is_general": false,
            "topic": {
                "value": "",
                "creator": "",
                "last_set": "0"
            },
            "purpose": {
                "value": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "creator": "",
                "last_set": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "created": "xxxxxx",
            "creator": "xxxxxx",
            "is_archived": false,
            "is_member": true,
            "num_members": 2,
            "is_general": false,
            "topic": {
                "value": "",
                "creator": "",
                "last_set": "0"
            },
            "purpose": {
                "value": "xxxxxx",
                "creator": "xxxxx",
                "last_set": "xxxx"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the output of the api. I anonymized everything because of tokens and IDs.

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(channelJSON);
foreach (JProperty prop in root["channels"].Children<JProperty>())
{
    JObject Channel = (JObject)prop.Value;
    ChannelList.Add(new SlackChannel(Channel["name"].ToString(), Channel["id"].ToString()));
 }
```

This is the code I am using. The foreach loop never completes, I placed breakpoints in the loop, but only the foreach line executes, then the code stops. What am I doing wrong. I want to iterate through the json response, getting the name and ID for each channel. I got the C# code from another question, and modified it, but I'm not getting any execution of the code.

Comment: Haven't used `json.net`, but the `channels` property is an array, so a standard for loop should iterate the array, then for each index of the array, do a `for in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialize a json with Json.Net, you can use this :

Generate a class with your Json and [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) :

```
public class Topic
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string creator { get; set; }
    public string last_set { get; set; }
}

public class Purpose
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string creator { get; set; }
    public string last_set { get; set; }
}

public class Channel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string creator { get; set; }
    public bool is_archived { get; set; }
    public bool is_member { get; set; }
    public int num_members { get; set; }
    public bool is_general { get; set; }
    public Topic topic { get; set; }
    public Purpose purpose { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool ok { get; set; }
    public List<Channel> channels { get; set; }
}
```

And use this line from the [doc](http://james.newtonking.com/json) :

```
RootObject m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

voila.

Comment: Thank you for the json2csharp link. Bookmarked for sure.

Comment: In fact there is another method to get this without json2csharp. The key is an addon for Visual Studio.

Comment: @JoenJ.Olsen He is native in VS2012+ and the addon is Microsoft Web Developer Tools. [pic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N1KBR.jpg)

Comment: I wonder how I haven't noticed that before now. Thank you for finding it again! Now I'm even able to do it for XML as well, which is quite awesome since I work with XML pretty much every day.

Comment: @user3500033 are you sure your json is valid ? are your sure that your string contain the whole json ? By the way, you should read all the code your generate.